# Getting Ad Type (photo, video, carousel, lead generation, etc) in Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to figure out how to get the ad type for any given ad. Currently there are 6 ad types on Facebook: Images, Videos, Carousels, Slideshows, Collections and Leads.

I tested the object_type value on the [Ad Creative endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative) but it only returns photo and video values. For other types, like Carousels, Facebook just returns "SHARE".

Is there some other way to query a given ad to get its creative type?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this via Facebook API. You need to fetch the creative for the given ad with `object_story_spec` and then use the data given there to identify the type of ad.